# isotropic density function

Tags: mathematical-statistics

A random vector $X \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is said to be $\textit{isotropic}$ if its density function can be written as 
\begin{equation*}
  f(x) = \tilde{f}(\|x\|) 
\end{equation*}, so how can i proof the following

If $X$ is isotropic and $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}\left[g(\|X\|)\right] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m}g(\|x\|)f(x)dx = \frac{2\pi^{m/2}}{\Gamma(m/2)}\int_{0}^{\infty}g(r)\tilde{f}(r)r^{m-1}dr.
\end{equation}.

Comment: Try to spot the surface of the unit sphere in the last integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hyperspherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates) to do this in a methodical (but longer) way if you don't recognize things like the surface area of an $m$-dimensional unit sphere per @Xian's comment. Starting with
$$
I = \int_{\mathbb R^m} g(\|x\|)\tilde f(\|x\|)\,\text dx
$$
we can put this in hyperspherical coordinates by letting $r = \|x\|$ and then the remaining angles are all completely integrated over, so using the Jacobian of $r^{m-1}\sin^{m-2}\theta_1\sin^{m-3}\theta_2\dots\sin \theta_{m-2}$ we get
$$
I = \int_{\theta_{m-1} = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\theta_{m-2} = 0}^\pi \dots \int_{\theta_1=0}^\pi\int_{r=0}^\infty g(r)\tilde f(r) r^{m-1}\sin^{m-2}\theta_1\sin^{m-3}\theta_2\dots\sin \theta_{m-2}\,\text d\theta_{m-1} \text d\theta_{m-2} \dots \text d\theta_1 \text dr
$$
which can be split into separate integrals so
$$
I = 2\pi \cdot \left[\prod_{k=1}^{m-2} \int_{0}^\pi \sin^{k}\theta \,\text d\theta\right]\cdot \int_0^\infty g(r)\tilde f(r) r^{m-1}\,\text d r.
$$

I'm going to assume $m \geq 4$ because the other cases can be handled with the more usual polar and spherical coordinates and I don't want to have to make exceptions for these cases.

For the product of sine integrals, we can look up the values in e.g. the [wikipedia article on particular definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_definite_integrals#Definite_integrals_involving_trigonometric_functions). That article integrates over $[0,\pi/2]$ but splitting our integrals into $[0,\pi/2]\cup(\pi/2, \pi]$ and substituting $u = x-\pi/2$ in the second one, we have
$$
\int_0^\pi \sin^k(x)\,\text dx = 2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^k(x)\,\text dx
$$
and can then use the formulas as written.

The key thing to note is the way that successive products annihilate. The product starts at $k=1$ so consider the successive terms $k = 2n-1$ and $k=2n$:
$$
\int_0^\pi \sin^{2n-1}(x)\,\text dx \cdot \int_0^\pi \sin^{2n}(x)\,\text dx \\
= 4 \cdot \frac \pi 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2n} = \frac \pi n
$$

From this we see that if $m$ is even, so $m-2$ is too, then
$$
2\pi \prod_{k=1}^{m-2} \int_{0}^\pi \sin^{k}\theta \,\text d\theta = 2\pi \frac{\pi^{m/2-1}}{(m/2-1)!} = \frac{2 \pi^{m/2}}{\Gamma(m/2)}
$$
as desired.

If $m$ is odd then we have
$$
2\pi \prod_{k=1}^{m-2} \int_{0}^\pi \sin^{k}\theta \,\text d\theta = \\
2\pi \left[\prod_{k=1}^{m-3} \int_{0}^\pi \sin^{k}\theta \,\text d\theta\right]\int_0^\pi \sin^{m-2}(x)\,\text dx \\
= 2\pi \frac{\pi^{(m-3)/2}}{((m-3)/2)!} \cdot 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{m-2}(x)\,\text dx.
$$
Letting $m-2 = 2k+1$ so $k = \frac{m-3}{2}$ I have
$$
2\pi \frac{\pi^{(m-3)/2}}{((m-3)/2)!} \cdot 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{m-2}(x)\,\text dx = \\4\frac{\pi^{k+1}}{k!} \frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!}.
$$

I'll leave this to you to prove, but you can prove the following result to get this in the form we want (I'd recommend using induction):

**Lemma**: for $k=1,2,3\dots$, 
$$
\frac{(2k)!!}{(2k+1)!!k!} = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2\Gamma\left(k + \frac 32\right)}.
$$

---

Using this lemma and substituting $k = \frac {m-3}2$ in, you should be able to finish the proof.

Comment: Oh thanks, I am really appreciate for your fantastic answer